# Laravel user_id in Many-To-Many relationships

Tags: php, laravel, relationship, laravel-5.4

Firstly sorry for my bad English.

---

I have three simple Models:

**User**

```
class User extends Authenticatable
{
    protected $fillable = [
        'first_name', 'last_name'
    ];

    public function tickets()
    {
        return $this->hasMany(Ticket::class);
    }

}
```

**Ticket**

```
class Ticket extends Model
{
    protected $fillable = ['user_id', 'title'];

    public function user()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo(User::class);
    }

    public function replies()
    {
        return $this->hasMany(TicketReply::class);
    }
}
```

**TicketReply**

```
class TicketReply extends Model
{

    protected $fillable = ['user_id', 'ticket_id', 'text'];

    public function user()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo(User::class);
    }

    public function ticket()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo(Ticket::class);
    }
}
```

So, For creating a new Ticket it needs to create a Ticket and a Reply.

I'm using below method in TicketController for creating new Ticket :

```
public function createNewTicket(Request $request)
{
    $ticket  = $request->user()->tickets()->create($request->all());
    $replies = $ticket->replies()->create($request->all()); // Error occurs in this line
}
```

But it returns this error :

> SQLSTATE[23502]: Not null violation: 7 ERROR: null value in column
>   "user_id" violates not-null constraint ...

**The Question Is :**

Why Laravel doesn't recognize the owner of TicketReply ?!

I hope I've explained clear enough.

**P.S:**

Be aware of `$request` data is like this :

```
array:2 [▼
  "title" => "My Ticket Title" // `title` field of Ticket Model
  "text" => "Ticket Text Goes Here" // `text` field of TicketReply Model
]
```

Comment: add `dd($ticket)` here

Comment: I can't `dd($ticket)`. Because error occurs exactly in the `$ticket = ....` line.

Comment: if TicketReply `belongsTo(User::class)`, shouldn't User `hasMany->(TicketReply::class)`?

Comment: @TomaszRup No...

Comment: what does your migration look like?

Answer (score 0):

I think you can't set user id on creating a replay to ticket as the model has only one foregin key, you can make a work around like this:

```
$replies = $ticket->replies()->create($request->all() + ['user_id' => $request->user()->id]);
```

Comment: Error occurs when I'm trying to create a new `TicketReply` for a `Ticket`.

Answer (score 0):

We think that the right solution is manually specify the user ID and ticket. 
**Good luck!**

Answer (score 0):

Laravel can't know it. It just knows that one field among others is the user_id on the ticket but it doesn't know that you want to use it. Also it looks like the code with that relationship not the 100% correct design.

What you want is:

```
user has many tickets
user has many ticketreplies
ticket belongs to user
ticket has many ticketreplies
ticketreply belongs to ticket
ticketreply has many users
```

Then create the ticket like you do and

Create the ticketReply like:

```
$fields = $request->all();
$fields['user_id'] = $request->user()->id;
$ticket->replies()->create($fields);
```

There are other ways as well, i.e.

```
$fields = $request->all();
$fields->user_id = $request->user()->id;
$fields->ticket_id = $ticket->id;
$ticketReply = \App\TicketReply::create($fields);
```